# When sharing a Jdbc connection pool between spring-data-jpa and spring-security-oauth's JdbcTokenStore, how to handle transactions?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We are using the JdbcTokenStore from spring-security to persist oAuth2 access tokens. The same application does also heavily rely on spring-data-jpa. Both share a connection pool to a MySQL database.

Jdbc defaults to auto-commit mode and JdbcTokenStore appears to be written with the assumption that auto-commit is on. It never explicitly commits a change.

Spring-data and JPA on the other hand require a transaction for write operations. The application uses the @Transactional annotation.

We are observing the following issue:

- Request (1): A client obtains an access token. JdbcTokenStore INSERTs this into the database.
- Request (2): Then, the client uses this access token in a subsequent request. This request is rejected since the token cannot be found in the database.

This behaviour could be explained if transaction from request (1) was not yet committed.

I'm not very familiar with the internals of Spring. Is it possible that the following happens?

- Some JPA operation acquires JDBC connection #1 from the pool, sets auto-commit=off, executes any number of SQL statements, and, then, commits.
- Request (1): JdbcTokenStore acquires the same JDBC connection #1, executes INSERT statement. (This now happens inside a transaction. This is not committed.)
- Request (2): JdbcTokenStore acquires a different JDBC connection #2, executes SELECT statement. (This does not see the uncommitted transaction.)
- Some JPA operation acquires JDBC connection #1 again and commits. (Now the oAuth token is committed.)

What configuration would avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot explain the root cause, we have found a fix: Switching to  the [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) JDBC connection pool (replacing Tomcat) eliminated all symptoms of the describe issue.